# Organize FragmentActivity navigation stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The application(target API level must be 7th) has `FragmentActivity` which analyzes at `onCreate` the fragment key passed as an extra.

Now what is needed is to reorder to front the activity that is already created with the given fragment key.

Let's say the `FragmentActivity` with different fragment keys are  `FA1`, `FA2` and `FA3` - each is the same activity Class instance with different fragments.

Now in the stack `FA1` > `FA2` > `FA3` i want to use the intent rather than the back button to get to `FA2`, by default that gives:

`FA1` > `FA2` > `FA3` > new `FA2`.

I'd like to get either `FA1` > `FA3` > `FA2` as the `FA3` might have some pending operations,  `FA1` > `FA2` is not as good but definitely better than default.

If there were several activities I'd use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag for intents, but that does not work for this case.

---

`FA1, FA2, FA3, etc.` are all the instances of the same class `MyFA`, that's why I'm not able to use the intent flag and the FragmentManager seems to be out of help until there's a standard global fragments cache.

---

**Milestone (currently working and to be improved) solution** One thing I've learned today is [activity-alias](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) which allowed to make several aliases for the same activity with the different Intent extras used as id's. Now with the REORDER_TO_FRONT flag it works as I wanted.

**Solution feedback** The solution has no low-level operations, I like a lot more than digging at the tasks or back-stacks. Now the drawback is that each of such activities needs a separate alias with the hardcoded path, I don't really like it.

**Requirements (bounty is here)** Whoever comes with a decent optimization takes <s>150</s> 300 cookies. Not bad ? Any other solid solution is also highly appreciated.

Currently I have like 10 aliases at application manifest, e.g.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.FragmentActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="com.company.name.intent.FragmentActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.company.name.intent.FragmentActivity.FragmentedOne"
        android:targetActivity=".activity.FragmentActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.name.intent.FragmentActivity.FragmentedOne" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="fragment_key_extra"
            android:value="FragmentOne" />
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name="com.company.name.intent.FragmentActivity.FragmentedTwo"
        android:targetActivity=".activity.FragmentActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.company.name.intent.FragmentActivity.FragmentedTwo" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="fragment_key_extra"
            android:value="FragmentTwo" />
    </activity-alias>
```

And then the activities are reordered with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
"com.company.name.intent.FragmentActivity.FragmentedOne");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your activity-alias? I have one activity with a fragment that switches between 8 different views (activities). I'd like to be able to go back and forth using REORDER to front.

Comment: Hi @Vee, I've added a part of the manifest file and a little snippet, hope it helps you - it should work. There might be a few typos as I had to change the text a little.

Comment: When you say "targetApi=7" you mean "minSdk=7" or "targetSdk=7"?

Comment: @shkschneider `minSdkVersion="7"` and I'm going to set `targetSdkVersion="8"` (in order to support the SD-card installation), for now it is `"7"` not to let myself to use any incompatible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your idea of using `activity-alias` to solve this issue, I wrote a [Historian class](https://gist.github.com/3992032) that will do the following:

- Scan the Activity list in your package for aliases to your specific Activity.
- Set up a lookup table that maps each alias to an Intent.
- Provide a `startActivity()` and `activityDestroyed()` methods that will do some bookkeeping so the lookup table can be used to dynamically assign an alias to a running Activity based on the Intent.

Here's an example on how to use it:

- in AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <activity android:name=".MyFragmentActivity">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity-alias android:name=".Alias0" android:targetActivity=".MyFragmentActivity" />
  <activity-alias android:name=".Alias1" android:targetActivity=".MyFragmentActivity" />
  <activity-alias android:name=".Alias2" android:targetActivity=".MyFragmentActivity" />
  <activity-alias android:name=".Alias3" android:targetActivity=".MyFragmentActivity" />
  <activity-alias android:name=".Alias4" android:targetActivity=".MyFragmentActivity" />
  ```
- within your Activity class

  ```
  public class MyFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity
          implements Historian.Host {

      private Historian<MyFragmentActivity> mHistorian;

      // ...

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          mHistorian = new Historian<MyFragmentActivity>(this);

          // ...
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          mHistorian.activityDestroyed(this);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean matchIntent(Intent intent0, Intent intent1) {
          if (intent0 == null || intent1 == null) return false;
          final String title0 = intent0.getStringExtra("title");
          final String title1 = intent1.getStringExtra("title");
          return title0.equals(title1);
      }

      // ...

  }
  ```

Instead of starting a new instance of your activity like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyFragmentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", newActivityTitle);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
```

You do this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyFragmentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", newActivityTitle);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    mHistorian.startActivity(this, intent);
```

So you still need to add a few `activity-alias` into your manifest manually (to be used as a pool) and implement the `matchIntent()` method in your Activity (to help detect whether two Intents are equal to you) but the rest is handled dynamically by the Historian class.

I haven't tested the code exhaustively, but it seems to work fine on some simple tests that I did. The idea is actually very similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12164426/1023092) on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12090256/1023092) (just need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` there) but using the `activity-alias` instead of the inner child classes make it much cleaner :)

Comment: It looks nice, did you use Historian in the applications supporting Android 2.1 ? I'm interested in it's performance and stability.

Comment: I tested it on emulator with 2.1 and do not notice any difference compared to when I run it on 2.3/4.0. Performance-wise, I think it should be more efficient compared to the solution involving `onActivityResult()` since we do not need to go through the lifecycle events of the intermediate activities. I haven't really tested this much though :)

Answer (score 4):

This answer is worth 300 cookies :-D  Mmmmm

1. **Extend Application so we can create our own back stack list with a global scope.**

   import android.app.Application;
   import android.content.Intent;

   class MyApp extends Application {

   ```
   //This is our very own back stack.
   private ArrayList<Intent> backStack = new ArrayList<Intent>();

   public void reorderBackStack(){
       //Do what you want to the order of your backstack
       //You can read the value of your intent extras from here.
   }

   public void addIntent(Intent i){ // this gets called from our activities onCreate
       backStack.add(i);
   }

   public void goBack(){
       if(backStack.size() >= 2){ // can go back
           backStack.remove(backStack.size() - 1); // drop the last item in stack if you want.  This is how Android does it.  (no forward capability)
           this.startActivity(backStack.get(backStack.size() - 1));
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. **Add a reference to our custom back stack in our activity.**

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        MyApp myapp;

   ```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myapp = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
        myapp.addIntent(this.getIntent()); //add the intent for this instance to backStack.
        myapp.reorderBackStack(); // call this anytime we need to reorder the back stack.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent){
        this.setIntent(newIntent);
        myapp.addIntent(this.getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    // We won't be using the back stack we will be using our own list of intents as a back stack so we need to override the back button.
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            myapp.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```

   }
3. **Override the back button so we can use our own back stack instead of Android's.**

**Edit**

I put together a proof of concept.

- Pros

  - No Aliases
  - Completely dynamic and reusable
  - Low level control
  - Easy to use (Extend CustomBackStackActivity instead of FragmentActivity or Activity)
- Cons

  - Not an out-of-the-box solution.  Will require tweaking and debugging.

The [.apk is Here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2BD9i1zpmm5VGNMR0pWaHI5R28) on my google drive.

The complete [project folder is here](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B2BD9i1zpmm5ODFyZ3FDOTRSUzg/edit).

Zipped [downloadable project folder is here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2BD9i1zpmm5R0YwcExiSWMxTmM).

Please don't complain about my code.  I know I used strings where I should have used constants and I duplicated code instead of seperating it and my spacing isn't perfect and I used excessive loops and objects.  I haven't sorted out the savedInstanceState.  Again, this is just a proof of concept. It works and I thought it might help someone.

Comment: This solution can be expanded on to add any functionality that your app requires.

Comment: Thanks, I like the style, but can not see how does it help to avoid or optimize the aliases. The main point of the question is about using REORDER_TO_FRONT or custom solution with the same behavior, the app has the main Activity class used for almost all the fullscreen views. Any ideas about how not to produce a bunch of subclassing activities nor declaring a static set of aliases ? I'd like to make it as much dynamic and beautiful as possible.

Comment: Each instance of an activity will add it's own intent to your list with extras and flags intact. This should give you all the tools you need to sort, and recall instances of one or multiple activities how ever you see fit. You said your fragment are distinguished by Intent extra. So in your reorderBackStack method you check for the added extra that distinguishes them and act accordingly. Without knowing how your application is structured I cant be more specific.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the intent might be reused this way, interesting, many thanks.

Comment: I'm going to check this pattern, probably during the weekend.

Comment: I managed to make it working by adding `private Activity lastActivity = null;` and calling lastActivity.startActivity(..)  instead of this.startActivity(..) as startActivity(..) might be called with the desired flags only from the activity, it throughs the exception being called from outside if activity context. Still I have a feeling that this solution is way too expansive to implement as I'll need to reorder the list as well. I also had to use activities aliases in order to reorder activities which makes the whole procedure excessive.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into using the functionality provided by the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html).  It has functions such as `popBackStack`.

You can also use [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) to add fragments to the backstack. You can use `addToBackStack` to accomplish this.

So with these two classes you should be able to reorder your fragments in the backstack as necessary.

Comment: I do apologize, the target API level must be 7th, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I believe all of the fragment classes are available through the support library: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html

Comment: That's cool, so i'm gonna try to make the fragment key to be it's tag,  that will probably do it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as I'm creating and pushing the same acivity with the different fragments distinguished by Intent `extra`. Meaning the activity always has one fragment at backStack, the answer would be correct for a single activity to manage the fragments stack. So to make the last question sentence clear: there's a single activity class but several instances having one fragment each.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

**1.** In your `FragmentActivity` implement a `Interface` for the callback from Fragment to Activity.

**2.** When you start any Fragment put it in back stack with the argument or tag `(addToBackStack(String arg0))`with the help of which you can pop up with that tag.

**3.** When you need to reorder the fragments then call the method of the interface which you implemented with proper arguments as per requirement and then use `popBackStack(String arg1, String arg2)` to get the fragment with the tag you put it in the backstack.

Comment: Thanks, that is more clear explained but is the same as the first answer, as I explained it appeared not to work as after the new Intent is processed I'm getting the new fragments backStack for the `FragmentActivity` instance. I mean if only the backStack would be shared that would be possible, but I'm creating the new activities to show.

Comment: you need not to use onNewIntent for this approach.

Comment: I don't use `onNewIntent` anywhere, but `onCreate` choosing the fragment to show based on the `Extra` value. This gives me the FragmentActivities stack with a single fragment, but they share the code of UI surrounding the fragment and other activities classes are also used, so I'd really prefer to have the activities stack. If I had to manage both the fragments and activities stack reordering that would be a little disaster.

Comment: the above solution is only for managing the  fragment stack and let me know what is the situation where you need to maintain the stack for activity?Please provide your navigation in the app.

Comment: Sure, the idea is to have the tab-bar below the displayed `fragment`, the fragmentActivity displays almost every piece of the app content. The appropriate fragment is chosen (at `FA` `onCreate`) by the String Extra. For the special cases I had to use other activities classes so I'm actually having a mix of `FA1 - FA2 - CA1 - CA2 - FA3`. I realize that was not in the OP, and I'm sorry this mistake. Your solution looks great for the `FA`, could it happen that you know a good way to extend it ? Oh, and all the navigation is driven by Intents with Extra for FA and w/o such an extra for `CA`.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered something similar, but the solution is not the best as FA1 > FA2 > FA3 will take you to FA1 > FA2 rather than FA1 > FA3 > FA2.

[My answer was for question : How to tag Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215566/833622)

Anyway, I edited the code a bit to use a "tag" which will be a string, but I think you can use the main solutions that uses integer indices. In summary, this should allow you to `fallBackToActivity` with a certain TAG. I am not sure how will each Activity decide what will its tag be, but again, in my previous answer it was a simple matter of an incremental integer.

```
package sherif.android.stack.overflow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SuperActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static String EXTRA_INDEX = "SUPER_INDEX";
    private static int RESULT_FALLBACK = 0x123456;
    private String tag; //this is your tag
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getIntent()!=null) {
            tag = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_INDEX, "default_tag");
        }
    }
    protected final String getIndex() {
        return tag;
    }
    protected final void fallBackToActivity(String tag) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INDEX, tag);
        setResult(RESULT_FALLBACK, intent);
        finish();
    }
    //@Override
    //public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    //  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INDEX, getIndex());
    //  super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    //}
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_FALLBACK) {
            if(!data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_INDEX, "default_tag").equals(getIndex())) {
                setResult(RESULT_FALLBACK, data);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it mean I need to call `fallBackToActivity` before starting the intent for the previous activity ? I mean the stack is dynamic and probably the `fallBackToActivity` method should return the status callback then. Thank you for the answer, please let me know what you think about this little clarification.

Comment: Do you need to start a new intent? This will go back to the activity with the specified tag. If you fallBackToActivity TAG1, it will return to activity with tag=TAG1 and onActivityResult will be called with the Intent that you set in `setResult`? This will not work?

Comment: As I said, the stack is dynamic and I can't predict whether the target activity is there - meaning I might want to start a new one instead of falling back. Without a callback of `fallBackToActivity` how do I understand whether the new activity should be started or I have the previous on top ?

Comment: @A-Live If you use integers as indices, it is as simple as checking if the activity you want has an index less than the current Activity's index.

Comment: If you check the original answer, It uses indices and overrides the startActivityForResult. You can override it and inside it, choose whether to fallBack or start a new activity. I would like to know how to achieve the transition to `FA1 > FA3 > FA2` though.

Comment: Well my current solution for `FA1 > FA3 > FA2` works pretty well except that you have to add many aliases for each FA/fragment pair. With the unique aliases the solution is as simple as to use REORDER_TO_FRONT flag, I'm looking for the way to optimize the solution now.

Comment: But I supposed it is dynamic, so you might need `unknown` aliases? Well if it is only a matter of `messy`, then I think the functionality provided makes this messiness rather acceptable.

Comment: Alright, the little mess must be fine for now as the alternatives look too overwhelming at this point, I'm happy to learn some new patterns though. Let me check later if that's possible to assign several bounties to give an adequate reward.